# Horizontal align content in div element

Tags: css

I'm new to html, css e.g.. I am practicing atm, and trying to make a personal website/blog. At the moment I am writing an "autor info" section in the blog template html doc.

At the CSS I am having trouble horizontally aligning the elements in my div element. I've tried checking other answers and questions, but none seems to work for me.

I've pasted the code down below. I've wrapped everything in an `.blog__info__author` `div` element. What I want to center is: `#blog__info__author__avatar`, `.blog__info__author__name`, `.blog__info__author__date-read`, `.blog__info__share`.

Anyone who can help? Lol, I know the code might not be perfect atm, still practicing and cleaning up. Trial and error you know..

```css
.blog__info__author {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: salmon;
}

#blog__info__author__avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.blog__info__author__name {
  color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.blog__info__author__date-read {
  color: rgb(146, 146, 146);
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.blog__info__share {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: It could be easy to understand if you add `HTML` also...

Comment: If you are new to css i'll suggest to study flexbox or grid and don't use floated elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the element where you want the things you want to center:

```
.container {
    ...
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: @Sfili_81, thank you I needed this "best practice" stuff. I've seen it around and ill go check it out